# Cannot read property 'original' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I can't put state in a constant. I'm managing state in a function where on button click I only increment it by 1. That works fine, but when I try to use that state somewhere else in application I get this error.

I've tried putting state in variable first then put it in constant.

```
          const Gallery = (
                <div className={classes.Gallery}>
                    <Image src={images[{...this.state.imageNumber}].original} />
                    <button onClick={this.nextImageHandler}>
                        Click Me!
                    </button>
                </div>
          );
```

Comment: This `images[{...this.state.imageNumber}].original` doesn't make sense. You are indexing `images` with an object. Take a look at [Spead in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: When I set it to images[0].original it works just fine. this.state.imageNumber is just a number in state that changes

Comment: Should be `images[this.state.imageNumber].original` probably

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to access a property of a javascript variable without first checking if it is defined. See [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

You are also not indexing your array properly and you are abusing the spread operator (`...`). There is no reason to spread a number. `...5` has no real semantic meaning.

```
console.log({...5}); // yeilds {}
```

That means you are trying to do `images[{}]` and means you are trying to index your array with the string `[object Object]`. This is probably not what you meant to do. You should just do `images[this.state.imageNumber]`.

With regards to your error `Cannot read property 'original' of undefined`, I imagine it's likely because you never initialized your state. As a result, `this.state.imageNumber` is `undefined`. That means you are indexing your array like `images[undefined]`. What you should do is either handle the `undefined` case or initialize your state to some sensible default.

Something like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { imageNumber: 0 };
    ...
    render() { ... }
}
```

At any rate, I would suggest you consider taking a javascript ramp-up course, as you are confusing fundamentals of javascript with reactjs and this may make it difficult for you to debug problems with either.